# bokeh server: get client IP adress without embedding in Django/Flask/

Tags: python, authentication, server, tornado, bokeh

In a bokeh server app i'd like to read the client IP adress and depending on that adress adjust the returned content.
Is this possible without embedding bokeh into django/flask/..?

Thanks

Update: Like proposed a GitHub issue is created [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9252).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.3.4 (and upcoming 1.4) there is no way to obtain anything from the HTTP request other than the HTTP query arguments. You could open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss whether there are ways to make the request available.